# TypeScript new Map get previous entry

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

So I have a TypeScript Map of Symbols. e.g.

```
interface StepData {
    name : string,
}
const steps = new Map<symbol, StepData>();
```

And I have a current Step. e.g. `Symbol('Step 1')`
I know how to get the current Step

```
steps.get(currentStep);
```

But I don't know if How I am doing this is neat or even efficient.

```
  const incrementStep = () => {
    const identifiers = [...steps];
    for (const [index, [identifier]] of identifiers.entries()) {
      if (identifier === activeStep && index < (identifiers.length - 1)) {
        const [nextStep] = identifiers[index + 1];
        activeStep = nextStep;
        break;
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE? (so `currentStep` and `activeStep` should be defined and the map should have data in it)  Is the data in the map going to be static by the time you iterate or will you be adding to/removing from/modifying it (and if so can you show examples)?  How efficient do you need to be? Are there going to be tens/hundreds/thousands/millions of entries? Are you going to be incrementing every minute/second/millisecond/microsecond?

Comment: No, this is neither neat nor efficient. What are you trying to achieve by this? Why do you use symbols as keys in the map? Why do you use a `Map` instead of an array if you want indexed access?

Comment: Btw the title asks for the "previous" step but the question body shows an `increment` function